# Text color(light colors) variation is not possible in android using react native

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

> Actually i am creating a form ui using react native in that for labels
>   using light color like '#606060'. This color  appears properly in IOS
>   but in android it shows black color. But other colors that means dark
>   colors  appears properly in both android and IOS.How to achieve
>   these light colors  properly in android ?